# Get current logon security token for SHGetFolderPath from elevated permissions

Tags: winapi

I need to get system folders for current user via SHGetFolderPath, but in the installer application the system elevates this to the admin account and it returns admin account folders instead. How to get the security token for the current user? I tried this:

```
HANDLE token = NULL;
PWTS_SESSION_INFO sessions;
DWORD cnt = 0;
WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &sessions, &cnt);
for (DWORD i=0; i<cnt; i++)
{
    if (WTSActive == sessions->State)
    {
        WTSQueryUserToken(sessions->SessionId, &token);
        break;
    };
    sessions++;
};
```

But it doesn't really work. Any ideas?

Comment: See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160601-00/?p=93555 you must also load the user profile.

Comment: @SimonMourier - *you must also load the user profile* - but in this case user profile already loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible get shell process id (explorer), take token from it and use this token in query.

```
if (HWND hwnd = GetShellWindow())
{
    ULONG dwProcessId;
    if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId))
    {
        HANDLE hToken;
        if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId))
        {
            BOOL b = OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, &hToken);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            if (b)
            {
                if (0 <= SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, hToken, &pszPath))
                {
                    DbgPrint("<%S>\n", pszPath);
                    CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
                }
                CloseHandle(hToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sexy solution! Works nicely!